# Django internationalization doesn't work in my project

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I read the documentation, read some blogs and started applying internationalization in my project, but it doesn't work. Probably something is going wrong. Please take a look what is it that I am doing wrong.

I am a windows user, so I started installing gettext versions both shared and static from [this](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html) link.
then I made following changes in `settings.py`:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    ...
]

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
]
```

I already set the language code to French language. Then in my template namely `index.html` I added following code:

```
{% load i18n %}

<!-- within block content -->
{% trans "Hi" %}
```

Now that everything is set I run following code in console:

```
django-admin makemessages -l fr
```

I received this message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: skipped file requirements.txt in . (reason: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte)
processing locale fr
```

I have no idea if above stated error has anything to do with translating the text of the template. Anyway, then in `django.po` within locale directory I translated that text of template to french as following:

```
#: .\templates\index.html:29
msgid "Hi"
msgstr "Salut"
```

and run `django-admin compilemessages`, but when I run it the text is not translated. I don't know why? I followed every step for this basic setup.

Thank you for time and reading.

edit: This is the app structure of my project. Apologies that I don't know other way other than taking its screenshot. The translation content is in `index.html`

[image]

Comment: There seems to be an unprintable `\xff` character in your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: I couldn't find the error, so I deleted `requirements.txt` file. Still the content is not translated.

Comment: Please provide file structure with appname.

Comment: @KlausD. after deleting `requirements.txt` the error is gone.

Comment: But, still translation does not work?? Everything looks fine.

Comment: no it doesn't work. I am wondering how to debug the error and problem.

Comment: Which `django.po` have you edited ? The one in `en/LC_MESSAGES` or the one in `fr/LC_MESSAGES` ?

Comment: the one in `fr/LC_MESSAGES`

Comment: @Benbb96, there is no `en/LC_MESSAGES` in locale directory except `fr/LC_MESSAGES`

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar project structure, it worked for me set LOCALE_PATH to

```
LOCALE_PATH = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "locale"),)
```

and put my *locale* directory into *portfolio/portfolio* directory.